# Has there ever been an official "Room of Death"?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, product-identification

D&D knows Mimics and their relatives, the Lurker and Trapper. They are aberrations that mimic<sup>pun intended</sup> the floor and ceiling and have been used in conjunction with a stunjelly for years to make a room that lusts for adventurers to eat. Yes, *the room* will eat you. For example in this [2010 Screamsheet blog post](https://screamsheet1.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/the-room-of-death/) describes "The Room of Death" with many more monsters for Pathfinder, but I was very sure I have seen an older internet page that discussed the two aberrations with the stunjelly in an empty room configuration. After a quick search I could find where I had read it first: [Jared [von] Hindman's 2006 article](http://www.headinjurytheater.com/article73.htm) ranting about 30 years of stupid monsters includes the (empty) Room of Death but labeled it as "Trinity of Dungeon Terror".<sup>1</sup>

Other terms for such a setup I have seen or heard in discussions are Living Room, Killer Room and Room of Doom.

Has there ever been a **pre-2006**, **official** Dungeons and Dragons supplement, or Dragon Magazine article that employed the idea of the killer room that wants to eat you, consisting of 3 different monsters that make up the ceiling, wall and floor? The most iconic combination seems to be Lurker, Trapper and Stunjelly but the first mention might have used other monsters.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, I used his articles to build a house filled with monsters that imitate items to try to eat you but that's beside the point.

<sup>2</sup> A single Greater Mimics doesn't count. Neither does a House Hunter Mimic or a set of 3 mimics. It must be 3 monsters with different stats making up the ceiling, floor and walls.

Comment: Is that one monster making up all (presumably) four walls? and one more each for the floor and ceiling?

Comment: It might be helpful to know *why* you have these *specific* requirements. Like, why exactly 3 different monsters?

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Because that's the Jared von Hindman's Trinity of Dungeon terror, which seems to have been pivotal in getting the Room of Death popular.

Comment: @nijineko yes, the stunjelly was making all 4 walls, the floor and ceiling are separate monsters.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the one-sentence question here is "Has Jared von Hindman's Trinity of Dungeon terror ever been described in a pre-2006, official Dungeons and Dragons supplement, or Dragon Magazine article?"

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir that, or a similar setup.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Almost.

Tom Moldvay's 1981 D&D module X1 Castle Amber has a room that comes very close to reaching your requirements.

Area 8 of Castle Amber--"Servants' Quarters"--is a 20'x20' room with one entrance. The floor is entirely covered by a green slime, the ceiling is entirely covered by a black pudding, and a stone platform raised 2' above the floor has a grey ooze on it. There is a stone chest on the platform (the bait) which contains a generous treasure.

So the ceiling, floor, and 3-monster requirements are met, but it does not meet your wall requirement. Despite the shortcoming, it is possible that the Castle Amber room was the original inspiration for later "Killer Rooms," "Rooms of Doom," or "Rooms of Death."

NOTE - I realize that in later editions, green slime becomes a hazard rather than a monster, but in 1981, green slimes, black puddings, and grey oozes were all monsters.